# Create database for movies - Getting Started

Tags: c#, php, sql, asp.net

I just need some indications to get started on a personal project I have. As little as "install this and read that" will do.

**Project Overview**

I want to create a database for all the movies on my personal cloud drive and host it on a website available to everyone connected to my network.

**Required Features**

1)Sort movies by year or by actors.

2)Available to everyone on network.

3)Free.

4)This is optional, but I've heard of IMDB APIs that can be used with databases in order to populate "actor", "director", "year" etc... fields. It would be nice if I could use this.

**Background**

I am an engineering student and have always liked coding. I mostly use mathematics-oriented languages like matlab, fortran and c++. However, I have zero experience with anything web-related.

**Possible approach**

It looks like using ASP.NET framework with SQL is my best bet here. 
I have found [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs), however I am not sure this can satisfy requirement 1), 2) and 4).

I have also read a bit on the w3schools website, again which suggest that ASP.NET + SQL is the way to go.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Never start an SO question with "I understand this is a very vague question." It just screams "too broad." Which your question unfortunately is. It's also opinion-based. Please see here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @eddie_cat Removed first sentence. What I'm looking for is an opinion. I'm aware that there's more than one way to do this, which is why I'm overwhelmed.

Comment: I understand that! But SO is not really a good place for opinion questions. Hence the downvotes and probable closure. Try starting with small problems and building up to the features you want. You can do everything you've mentioned with ASP.NET and SQL. Maybe start by trying to pull data from an IMDB API. When you get that working, try putting it in your database. Sorting is easy with SQL. Just break it up. :)

Comment: It sounds like one direction you are heading is Database First Development. Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591506.aspx

Comment: "You can do everything you've mentioned with ASP.NET and SQL." was actually enough. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going to hit a dead end.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If this comes off as offensive, I don't mean it to.

It seems you are newer to programming, or at least the .net world of programming.  Given this I would try to do things very simple.

I would just try to make a simple app that can do what you want (store info, sort, filter, and be able to access a web api).

To make it easier for you to get started, here is what I would use to crank this out.

I would create a winForms app in c#.  I would use SQLServers new (LocalDB) to store my data.

That is it (for starting).  You will need to learn to use Ado.net, T-SQL, how to create tables, and if you want to access IMDB you can learn that API also and how to connect to that.

But start small.

Answer (score 2):

You need to research and look into a lot of this yourself. Buy a few books or google SQL for beginners.

You absolutely can do 1, 2, and 4 with SQL.

A good way to start this project would be looking into ER diagrams online and then going from there.

Also look into SQL Server or Oracle.